# What does the {lang:(?:da|en)} do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to understand what this state means in ui-router:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/{lang:(?:da|en)}',
  template: '<ui-view/>'
});
$stateProvider.state('app.home', {
  url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/home-page.html',
});
```

Specifically what does {lang:(?:da|en)} do.  I've not seen this construct before.

Comment: Looks to me like it creates a named selection "lang" that will contain either da or en depending on the language preference found in the URL.

Comment: As far as JavaScript is concerned, it is just a string with no special meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is using what is called **Regex Parameters** You can see their [documentation here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)

So, `/{lang:(?:da|en)}` means to check that the `lang` parameter is either `da` or `en`. If so, then render the template.

Specifically, this will match `/da`, or `/en`

Answer (score 2):

It's a [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher)

It is basically a regex that acept only da or en as lang parameter

**{}** indicate a placeolder

**lang** is the parameter name

**(?:da|en)** indicate the possible values

I think you're following this example -> https://fadeit.dk/blog/post/angular-translate-ui-router-seo

and indeed is not crystal clear